# Remove last parenthesized string in all file names in a directory

Tags: bash, zsh

I have many song files that I am trying to rename. I am trying to remove the last occurrence of a parenthesized string in all of the song file names. For example, they are formatted like this: `song - artist (foo) (bar) (text I want to remove).mp3`, but I want the output to be `song - artist (foo) (bar).mp3`.

Currently, I have found a zsh command that can delete all parenthesized strings as seen in an answer to this post [Renaming files to remove parenthesized strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466781/renaming-files-to-remove-parenthesized-strings).

The solution from that post that almost worked for me was to use this command:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '*' '${f//[[:space:]]#[(]*[)]}'
```

However, this removes **all** parenthesized strings in all the file names. I am only trying to remove the **last** occurrence of parenthesized strings in the file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bash's greedy regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

re='(.*)(\([^)]*\))(.*)'

for file in *; do
    if [[ $file =~ $re ]]; then
        echo mv -i -- "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]-}"
    fi
done
```

Filename expansion needs to be improved however.

Answer (score 2):

This task can also be done by using pattern matching, rather than a regular expression:

```
for f in *\(*\).*; do mv -- "$f" "${f% \(*\).*}"."${f##*.}"; done
```

Note that this is **not** `bash` specific; it should work in any POSIX shell.

Answer (score 1):

A version using `zmv`:

```
zmv -n '(*) \(*\).mp3' '$1.mp3'
```

With `-n`, this command lists what would change.  Remove the `-n` to actually rename the files.